# TP4056 doesn't work without power source connected

Tags: power-supply, solar-cell, solar-charge-controller, nodemcu

I have a problem with my TP4056 circuit.

[image: Schematic]

My goal is to (solar)power a [NodeMCU V3](https://www.amazon.de/AZDelivery-NodeMCU-ESP8266-ESP-12E-Development/dp/B06Y1ZPNMS/) with the [TP4056](https://www.amazon.de/IZOKEE-Lademodul-Einstellbar-Converter-Batteriehalter/dp/B07KW78QK8/). I simply connected the output from the TP4056 to VIN and GND from the NodeMCU board

The TP4056 works fine if the power source (the solar panel) is connected, but if I remove the solar panel, the battery doesn't power the NodeMCU.

The battery is fully charged.

Edit:
My idea is that if the power supply is disconnected, the TP4056 will automatically power the NodeMCU via the battery.
Can the TP4056 do this?
Or is there another/better solution?

Comment: 1) Include a schematic to explain how you connected everything. 2) Why do you expect the battery to power the TP4056 when the TP4056 doesn't have a power source connected? Would you like the battery to charge itself from its own power through the TP4056?

Comment: 1) I simply connected the output from the Tp4056 to VIN and GND from the NodeMCU board. I can add a schematic if necessary.

2) I expressed myself wrong. I meant that the battery does not power the NodeMCU.

Comment: Schematic is necessary.  I am now confused with this new comment.

Comment: See how it only creates **confusion** if you don't add a schematic. No need to paint it or make it to scale, as long as it is clear enough.

Comment: The TP4056 is not designed to do what you expect; it is a charger, it is not designed to power a load.

Comment: "The battery is fully charged." - exactly what voltage is the battery, and what voltage do you get on the TP4056 module's output terminals? (with the solar panel and NodeMCU disconnected). Module schematic [here](https://www.sunrom.com/p/lithum-battery-charger-with-protection-microusb)

Comment: I've added a schematic. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: A TP4056 simply **does not have "out" pins**.  Whatever you are using is either *not* a TP4056, or is a TP4056 plus additional circuitry on an **undocumented module**.  It will be impossible for anyone to help you until you can fully document what is actually in use.  Most likely however you have chosen the wrong part(s).

Comment: I used the TP4056 wich is linked in Question.

Comment: That’s a fritzing wiring diagram, not a schematic.

Answer (score 1):

Your battery maybe have a problem. If there is a 3.3V voltage regulator in the nodemcu you will have to put at least 3.7 volt there. Maybe your battery is not capable of supplying 3.7 volt.

Comment: This is something to keep in mind, but **it is not the primary problem here**.  The primary problem is that the asker expects the TP4056 to do something it is not designed to.

Comment: The battery has 4.2V. I even supplied the TP4056 directly with the battery and it worked.

Comment: So your nodemcu takes 3.3 volt. There are certain possibilities the regulator has a problem. There seems to be something missing from here.

Comment: Do you mean the regulator of the NodeMCU? Everything work works fine if the TP4056 is connected to a power source. But when I remove the power source, there is no power output. I expected that the TP4056 would power the NodeMCU via the battery.

Comment: From the image of the nodempu it uses an AMS117-3.3 LDO with a Dropout Voltage of 1.1V typ, 1.3V max.